# Do you have to be on the same WIFI for a Buffer Overflow attack to work?

Tags: network, wifi, exploit, buffer-overflow, ports

I know how Buffer Overflows work but in order to do them do you have to be on the same WIFI as your victim. You need to send a packet to a specific device on a specific port. Therefore, unless port forwarding was enabled on that specific port for that specific device, how would you exploit a buffer overflow vulnerability if you were on different WIFI? Thanks.

Comment: Buffer overflows is in the application and the way it gets and treats input,wifi has nothing to do with it

Comment: A buffer overflow *in what*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know how Buffer Overflows work

You have to learn a little more about that...

> in order to do them do you have to be on the same WIFI as your victim.

That's not even close to be correct.

> You need to send a packet to a specific device on a specific port.

No, this is normal network traffic.

> Therefore, unless port forwarding was enabled on that specific port for that specific device

... you cannot send packets to the destination. And that have nothing to do with a buffer overflow.

> how would you exploit a buffer overflow vulnerability if you were on different WIFI?

You use countless other ways, and exploiting a vulnerability on the same WIFI is not the fastest or the easiest way.

---

A buffer overflow happens when a program copies more data into a buffer than the available space. That data may come from the network, or from a text, or decoding an image. Anything that reads data, no matter from which source, can be vulnerable.

To exploit a buffer overflow without being on the same WIFI network, send an email with a crafted JPG file when the victim uses an outdated email client. Or a special PDF for a vulnerable Adobe Reader application. Or send the victim an USB drive with a LNK file and a special icon. There are lots of ways to exploiting a buffer overflow and the majority of them does not need you to be on the same network.